# Richfaces SuggestionBox  as a combobox doesn't disappear

Tags: combobox, richfaces, double-click

I am using Richfaces suggestionBox as a combobox. You can see this usage in the second example of livedemo: http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/suggestionBox.jsf?c=suggestionBox

The problem is that if I double click on the arrow icon, the suggestion box will not disappear after that. In fact, we just need to repeatedly click on the icon, the issue will occurs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A work-around here:
http://community.jboss.org/thread/164345?tstart=0